# angularjs 1.5 component one way binding not working with setInterval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components

I have a simple component that users a timer to increment a value in the view. I use setInterval to automatically increment the value and I use a button to also increment the value. Clicking the button works as expected, but setInterval does nothing, no error, no increment. Here is the code:

```
export default angular.module('directives.timer', [])
.component('timer',{

bindings:{
    count: '<'
},
template:`<div>{{$ctrl.count}}</div>
          <div><button ng-click="$ctrl.increment()">increment</button></div>
          <pre>{{$ctrl}}</pre>`,

controller: function(){
   this.count = 0;
   this.tick = function(){
       this.count = this.count++;
   }
   this.increment = function(){
       this.count++;
   }

   this.$onInit = function(){
       var _this = this;
       setInterval(function(){
           _this.tick();
       }, 1000);
   }
}
}).name
```

The tick function is called and the value is incremented but the UI is not updating.
What's wrong? Thanks

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with one way binding. You could change your bindings to be {} and this would still work. The very first thing your controller does is manually set a local property of count to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular is not aware that change happened, because you are changing the value outside of scope of angular. Instead use Angulars wrapper $interval.

[Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval):

> AngularJS's wrapper for window.setInterval. The fn function is
>   executed every delay milliseconds.

Comment: Exactly, the [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service is a wrapper that then triggers the digest cycle.